# How to write list values from a dictionary under the key header in a CSV as columns

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a csv file from a dictionary where each value is a list of numbers.

```
example = {"A" : [1,2,3], "B" : [1], "C": [4,5,6,7,8,9]}
```

I want the csv to be like:

```
A,B,C
1,1,4
2, ,5
3, ,6
 , ,7
 , ,8
 , ,9
```

I tried doing something like:

```
with open("example.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    headers = example.keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(example)
```

but it ended up with with something like this in excel:

```
A,B,C
[1,2,3], [1], [4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Some possible things I could think about doing is append an empty space to the smaller list values to have the same length as the longest list value, zip based on the index value then have each tuple be a row. If i do it this way tho, would there be an efficient way of finding the biggest list size and appending empty spaces without a lot of for loops and appending? The list size can be as big as 65000. Also the number of entries in the dictionary is variable, meaning its never a set constant.

Answer (score 2):

with just standard library (assume python 3.7+ - for order-preserving feature of dict necessary for the correct order of the keys in the header)

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

example = {"A" : [1,2,3], "B" : [1], "C": [4,5,6,7,8,9]}
keys, values = zip(*example.items())
data = (dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in zip_longest(*values, fillvalue=''))
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    wrtr = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=keys)
    wrtr.writeheader()
    wrtr.writerows(data)
```

EDIT: For python version before 3.7* you can not rely on order being preserved, so you need to explicitly provide the header in the desired order (i.e. it cannot come from the dict.keys())

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

header = ['A', 'B', 'C']
example = {"A" : [1,2,3], "B" : [1], "C": [4,5,6,7,8,9]}

values = (example.get(key, []) for key in header)
data = (dict(zip(header, row)) for row in zip_longest(*values, fillvalue=''))
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    wrtr = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
    wrtr.writeheader()
    wrtr.writerows(data)
```

- in 3.6 order-preserving feature is considered implementation detail and should not be relied upon.

Comment: @KevinLe Note that assume python3.7 and order-preserving property of the dict

Comment: Oh shoot, I just noticed that, what would occur with python 3.4, I'm running on a system that has programs running on python 3.4 and I'm not sure if updating could cause a problem with them. I have been doing development on another system with python 3.7 so that might be problematic on the development side

Comment: you can have multiple python version installed simultaneously. But I will update my answer

Comment: For what I'm doing, if I don't care about column order, such as A,C,B still being a valid csv, does dictionary order being preserved matter?

Comment: in this case it doesn't matter - original solution would do. Order preserving was important to ensure header ABC (assuming order of the keys is the order desired for header). Anyway I also provided solution if order of columns matter

Comment: Would it be more robust to do something like:
example.keys().sort() for the header?

Comment: It's up to you to if you want keys sorted in the header.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the pandas library try the following,

```
import pandas as pd

example = {"A" : [1,2,3], "B" : [1], "C": [4,5,6,7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in example.items() })
df.to_csv('example_dict.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution can be to convert the dictionary into dataframe and then use that for csv file, but keep in mind, still there is no way to assign non equal length array with blank values, it will be NaN.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example, orient='index') 
df = df.T           # Transpose dataframe to get same orientation as required
```

[image]